# Python, loop that gets a value then tests that value again

Tags: python

This is my first time asking here. I tried searching for an answer, but wasn't certain how to phrase what I need so I decided to ask.

I am working on a character creator for a tabletop RPG. I want to get the results for the character's previous occupation, which are on a list, then test that value again to get the occupation previous to that.

I already have a way of getting the first occupation, which is then compared with a text database, with entries such as:

Captain                                ,Explorer,Knight,Sergeant,

Where Captain is the first occupation and the commas mark the beginning and the end of the possible previous occupations. I have managed to get one of those randomly, but I haven't been able to make the loop then take the selected occupation and run it again. For example:

Explorer                               ,Cartographer,

Here's the simplified version of my code. It gets the first part right, but I'm not sure how to trigger a loop for the next.

```
import random  
def carOld(carrera,nivPoder):  
carActual=carrera  
u=0  
indPoder=int(nivPoder)  
carAnterior=[]    
commas=[]  
entTemp=[]  
d=open("listaCarreras.txt","r")  
f=(d.readlines())  
while indPoder!=0:  
    indPoder=indPoder-1          
    for line in f:  
        if carActual in line:  
            entTemp=line.split(",")         
d.close  
del entTemp[0]  
del entTemp[-1]  
print (entTemp)  
carAnterior=random.choice(entTemp)
```

Comment: instead of using whatever you are doing to split the words (your nested for loop with ifs and all that), you could split each line with `line.split(',')` which would make a list of words with a comma as your delimiter. that would be way better.

Comment: That was very helpful and is something I will definitely keep using in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this. I believe based on your description that the current occupation is in the front of the list, and the previous occupations are next in the list.

```
str_occs = 'Occ1,Occ2,Occ3'
list_occs = str_occs.split(',')

def prev_occ(occupation, list_occs):
    prev_occ_index = list_occs.index(occupation) + 1
    try:
        ret_val = list_occs[prev_occ_index]
    except:
        ret_val = "No prior occupations."

    return ret_val
```

You can try it out here: https://repl.it/B08A